# Java dynamic method creation

Tags: java, groovy, metaprogramming, cglib

I have following information in JSON format.

```
 [
  {
    "name": "A",
    "value": {
      "isValueApplicable": "true"
    }
  },
  {
    "name": "B",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "x",
        "isMandatory": "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "y",
        "isMandatory": "true"
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "C",
    "parameters": [
      {
        "name": "x",
        "isMandatory": "true"
      },
      {
        "name": "y",
        "isMandatory": "false"
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

What I want is, a class is created with following methods :

```
public Structure getA (String value) {
}

public Structure getB (String xValue, String yValue) {
}

public Structure getC (String xValue) {
}

public Structure getC (String xValue, String yValue) {
}
```

The important part here is, these methods should be created dynamically based on the information given in JSON. So, for A only value is applicable. For B, both values x and y are needed. But for C, only x value is mandatory and user can provide value for y, hence the 2 different methods.

Q. Is it possible in java to generate the methods at compile time after reading the JSON, like if the parameters are mandatory i will create method with those many parameters. If the value if not applicable then i will create method without any parameter.

Comment: seems like your json is not proper json. Please provide good json.

Comment: yes, it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can be done using `Reflection in Java` Or You can use `javaassit` and `cglib`

Comment: Reflection asks about classes and their members, you can change fields but you cannot create new ones. but suhashd wants to change method parameters also. That is why I wrote reflection.

Answer (score 0):

yes, you can generate Java bytecode on the fly. CGLib ([Github link here](https://github.com/cglib/cglib)) is one option to do that.

Or you can generate Java source code from Json with something like Jackson, and compile that. [Here's one example.](http://littlebigextra.com/how-to-convert-json-schema-to-java-classes-using-maven-plugin/)

I'm sure there are more ways, but yes, it's certainly possible.

Of course the Json you're showing is corrupt so would never yield anything but a parser error.